# Invertible Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an invertible matrix P and a matrix C such that A = PCP^−1, where the matrix A is given by

\begin{bmatrix}-1&-5\\4&7\end{bmatrix}.

How would I find P and C, by only knowing the values of A? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about $C=A$ and $P$ the identity matrix?

Answer (score 2):

There are several answers to your question. One (the simplest one) is $P=I, C=A$.

Furthermore, taking any invertible matrix $Q$, you can set $C=Q^{-1}AQ$ and $P=Q$, and you have

$$PCP^{-1} = Q(Q^{-1}AQ)Q^{-1} = (QQ^{-1})A(QQ^{-1}) = IAI=A$$